# phpunit works in cmd but not in NetBeans

Tags: php, unit-testing, netbeans, phpunit

I have problem with NetBeans.
I installed PHPUnit and updated configuration in Netbeans for Unit testing, but when I closed NetBeans and opened it next time PHPUnit don't works.
I tested absolute path of PHPUnit in cmd and it works well:

`C:\WebServers\usr\local\php5\phpunit.bat --version`

Result is:

```
PHPUnit 3.6.7 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

But in NetBeans I'm still getting error:

```
Selected PHPUnit (version ?.?.?) is too old, upgrade it if possible (the minimum version is 3.3.0).
```

[image: unit testing configuration]

[image: general php options]

Include_path in php.ini:

```
include_path=".;C:\WebServers\usr\local\php5\PEAR"
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like as if Netbeans is using some other PHPUnit version.

Comment: But in configuration I typed right path to right version of PHPUnit :(

Comment: Try updating your netbeans to the new 7.1 version. I know there was a similar issue with the previous version of Netbeans.

Comment: Does C:\WebServers\usr\local\bin\php --ini produce the expected ini path? Maybe add the C:\WebServers\usr\local\php5\PEAR to the global includes? It seems fine apart from that :/

Answer (score 0):

Your phpunit.bat is probably pointing to a different PHP install than what Netbeans is using.  This is particularly probable if you're the same guy I tried to help with the same issue last week (who had it working on a desktop but not a laptop).

Please check and tell me if you have multiple php.exe s in your system.

The probable solution is to take the include_path from the first php.exe in your system path and prepend it to the include_path in Netbeans' php.ini.